# Viewing s3 files in browser

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have created a bucket in s3 and successfully uploaded files to it with django storages. However, when I try to access the files in the browser, I get the following error:

`IllegalLocationConstraintException`
   The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint 
   this request was sent to.

I have also realised I do not have region name included in my URL(https://docs.s3.amazonaws.com/media/admin/2.pdf...).
Could that be the problem?
If so, how do I set it to append the region name?

What could be missing here?

Comment: Amazon S3 is smart enough to determine the region from the bucket name, so URLs do not require a region. However, the browser is probably trying to make an API call, which _might_ require that the request be sent to the correct region. Can you view the code that is causing the error so that you can show it to us?

Comment: Problem is I have 200 status code in my console so I don't know where in my code to look for an error.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Set `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` to `https://s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com` in `settings.py`. If you need to specify an alternate region in an override of `S3Boto3Storage` for a particular field, set the `endpoint_url` attribute to `s3.your-alternate-region-name.amazonaws.com`.

## Explanation

I finally figured this out after an embarrassing number of hours. According to [this comment on a boto3 repo issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3015#issuecomment-929675187) if a region was launched after 20 March 2019 (which both [eu-south-1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-open-aws-europe-milan-region/) and [af-south-1](https://press.aboutamazon.com/news-releases/news-release-details/aws-launches-region-south-africa/), the region I am using, were), then basically s3 requests are routed differently. Read the comment, but in order to fix this you need to specify which region the request is going to like so:

- This URL style works for all regions but the ones launched after 20 March 2019: `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/file_key.txt`. **Don't use this one**.
- For the regions launched post `20 March 2019` the URL needs to include the region name between the `.s3` and `.amazonaws.com` parts, like so:`bucket-name.s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com/file_key.txt`. Note that this style is backwards-compatible and works with all s3 regions. **Use this one**.

This means that we need to explicitly set the `endpoint_url` on all of these regions. We need to keep in mind that the `addressing_style` attribute for django-storages is set to `None`, meaning that boto3 will use the value `path` for this attribute. This means that if we set our `endpoint_url` to `bucket-name.s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com` on `S3Boto3Storage` override classes (like below) boto3 will prepend the `bucket_name` attribute to every s3 key. What you will end up with is something like `bucket-name.s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/file_key.txt` when we obviously only want `bucket-name.s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com/file_key.txt`. This is not documented in django-storages.

```
class IncorrectStorageSetup(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = "bucket-name"
    endpoint_url = "bucket-name.s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com"
    # addressing_style = None -> defaults to path type `addressing_style`.
```

Here is how to fix this.

Use `path` addressing style by leaving `AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE` to its default of `None` in `settings.py` and set `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` to `s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com`. This means that all URLs will take the correct form of `s3.your-region-name.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/file_key.txt`. Now, every time you override `S3Boto3Storage` you only need to set the `bucket_name` attribute if the bucket is in `your-region-name` that you set in `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` above, that is. If you want to use another region, explicitly set the `endpoint_url` attribute of the class to `s3.your-other-region-name.amazonaws.com` as well as the `bucket_name` attribute.

Note there is another way to fix this by using the converse, i.e. setting `AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE` to `virtual` with everything else configured the same. It should do the same thing but you need to explicitly set `AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE` which is one more step than above.